# Turning an attribute into a property on an object-by-object basis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I have a class of objects, most of whom have this one attribute which can in 95% of cases be implemented as a simple attribute. However, there are a few important edge cases where that property must be computed from data on another object.

What I'd like to be able to do is set `myobj.gnarlyattribute = property(lambda self: self.container.x*self.k)`.

However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> myfoo=foo()
>>> myfoo.spam
10
>>> import random
>>> myfoo.spam=property(lambda self: random.randint(0,20))
>>> myfoo.spam
<property object at 0x02A57420>
>>>
```

I suppose I could have `gnarlyattribute` always be a property which usually just has `lambda self: self._gnarlyattribute` as the getter, but that seems a little smelly. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give some more information here. Why is one object different to another? Are they actually different classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, properties can only work at the class level, and they can't be set on instances. (Well, they can, but they don't do what you want.)

Therefore, I suggest using class inheritance to solve your problem:

```
class NoProps(object):
    def __init__(self, spam=None):
        if spam is None:
            spam = 0  # Pick a sensible default
        self.spam = spam

class Props(NoProps):
    @property
    def spam(self):
        """Docstring for the spam property"""
        return self._spam

    @spam.setter
    def spam(self, value):
        # Do whatever calculations are needed here
        import random
        self._spam = value + random.randint(0,20)

    @spam.deleter
    def spam(self):
        del self._spam
```

Then when you discover that a particular object needs to have its `spam` attribute as a calculated property, make that object an instance of `Props` instead of `NoProps`:

```
a = NoProps(3)
b = NoProps(4)
c = Props(5)

print a.spam, b.spam, c.spam
# Prints 3, 4, (something between 5 and 25)
```

If you can tell ahead of time when you'll need calculated values in a given instance, that should do what you're looking for.

---

**Alternately**, if you can't tell that you'll need calculated values until after you've created the instance, that one's pretty straightforward as well: just add a factory method to your class, which will copy the properties from the "old" object to the "new" one. Example:

```
class NoProps(object):
    def __init__(self, spam=None):
        if spam is None:
            spam = 0  # Pick a sensible default
        self.spam = spam

    @classmethod
    def from_other_obj(cls, other_obj):
        """Factory method to copy other_obj's values"""
        # The call to cls() is where the "magic" happens
        obj = cls()
        obj.spam = other_obj.spam
        # Copy any other properties here
        return obj

class Props(NoProps):
    @property
    def spam(self):
        """Docstring for the spam property"""
        return self._spam

    @spam.setter
    def spam(self, value):
        # Do whatever calculations are needed here
        import random
        self._spam = value + random.randint(0,20)

    @spam.deleter
    def spam(self):
        del self._spam
```

Since we call `cls()` inside the factory method, it will make an instance of whichever class it was invoked on. Thus the following is possible:

```
a = NoProps(3)
b = NoProps.from_other_obj(a)
c = NoProps.from_other_obj(b)
print(a.spam, b.spam, c.spam)
# Prints 3, 3, 3

# I just discovered that c.spam should be calculated
# So convert it into a Props object
c = Props.from_other_obj(c)
print(a.spam, b.spam, c.spam)
# Prints 3, 3, (something between 3 and 23)
```

One or the other of these two solutions should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[The magic to make properties work](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) only exists at the class level. There is no way to make properties work per-object.